# Table not found after apparently successful migration

Tags: h2, flyway

I was using flyway through the CL to migrate my production DB (mySql), while I was using a fixed SQL query to create the DB, tables, etc. in my unit tests, using H2. I'd like now to better integrate flyway and create/delete DB after each unit test.

I have a DB factory and inside its build method I'm using the following code:

```
flyway.setLocations("filesystem:sql/migrations/common","filesystem:sql/migrations/h2");
flyway.setSchemas("MYSERVER");
flyway.setDataSource(
p.getProperty(DB_URL.getName()), 
p.getProperty(USERNAME.getName()), 
p.getProperty(PASSWORD.getName()));
flyway.setInitOnMigrate(true);
flyway.migrate();
```

The migrations seems to apply correctly, as I can see my SQL code from the flyway logs. But when I start using the DB, immediately afterwards, I get TABLE NOT FOUND errors. I'm using h2 as in memory DB with the following URL to initialize my client:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:MYSERVER;MVCC=true
```

Do you have any idea on what I might be making wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your JDBC url.

MYSERVER is the name of the database, not the schema.

The easiest thing to do is to let flyway use the same url, and not set a schema. This way you'll find everything in the public schema of the MYSERVER database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! If I understand correctly, I should remove the line  flyway.setSchemas("MYSERVER"); which doesn't seem to solve the issue :(

Comment: But bizarrely enough if I remove the mem attribute things start to get better

Comment: Im confused ... you say answer didn't solve the problem but it's marked as good. Now i get your same problem ... what is the solution? ... it's "mem"?

Comment: By the way and related (get from http://jkyamog.blogspot.com.es/2012/06/misconception-about-h2-in-memory-db.html) "... sometimes I have seen h2 url connection as "jdbc:h2:mem", which is different from "jdbc:h2:mem:".  The former will create a persistent db in the current path db called mem, the later will create a in memory db."

Comment: By removing the `:mem` portion, you're switching to a persistent database on disk - which avoids this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue - after digging around, it appears that the H2 database is being recreated between migration scripts somehow.

You can confirm this happens by putting a `SELECT * FROM migrations` in the first two migrations - it will succeed in the first and fail in the second.

According to the [H2 Documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases), specifying a database name and `;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` option should suffice to allow concurrent and subsequent accesses to the in-memory database, *however this is not the case*.

Upgrading Flyway from `3.1` to `3.2.1` has **fixed** the problem.