# How to setup a portable persistence.xml file?

Tags: java, maven, jpa, h2

I'm building an app that uses an `h2` database, my `persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="taskUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.github.tarrsalah.jersey.todo.app.model.Task</class>
        <properties>          
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:file:/home/tarrsalah/src/github.com/tarrsalah/jaxrs-todo-app/target/todo"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

As you can see I have a hard link in `javax.persistence.jdbc.url` property to a local `h2` database and I want to share my code on github.

How can I make a cloned version of my code works without changing the `persistence.xml` configuration file ?

(**PS**: I'm using flyway for database migration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sharing this code with others you can try using in-memory h2 database

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000"/>
```

Comment: How about the flyway migration ?

Comment: AFAIK flyway migration works in h2 in-memory database. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019874/table-not-found-after-apparently-successful-migration

Comment: @Shailendar the migration succeeded using the maven flyway plugin, but it seems that eclipseLink can't found it (I'm using the same URL).

Comment: I must migrate using the java API, thanks for suggestion the use of the memory option.